# Jquery datatable issue when Editing HUMHUB

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datatables

I am working on humhub social networking site. I need to add datatable for searching purpose and for that i haved already added the jquery and below where i added the jquery i have placed the cdn link of jquery datatable

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
```

and below that i have a javascript function to convert normal html table into jquery datatable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#vibed-music').DataTable();
});
</script>
```

So the library sequence is like this
1) jquery 2) jquery.datatables.js 3) juery.datatables.css
still i am getting an error of datatables() is not defined. Can you tell me why?

Comment: May want to load your CSS first. What version of jQuery are you loading? Any other errors?

Comment: Please also review: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve